# How to get reference to the repeat parent index in aurelia?

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

i want to know if it's possible to pass a repeat parent index to a converter in a repeat?
I tried this :

```
<div repeat.for="row of router.navigation | myFilter:1:$parent.$index">
```

but it's not working !
Any idees ?
Any workaround ?

Answer (score 8):

It's possible- the code you have above should work.  Here's a running example: https://gist.run?id=5df404d80be769a0d62aab2f7c9f300e

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./test-converter"></require>

  <div repeat.for="y of 3">
    <span repeat.for="x of 3">${ x * y | test : $index : $parent.$index }</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  message = 'Hello World!';
}
```

**test-converter.js**

```js
export class TestValueConverter {
  toView(value, x, y) {
    return `(${x},${y},${value})`;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not exactly what I want ! I want to use the converter like a filter. If I take your exemple, I don't want to display value when y is equal 2. So the filter is apply on 'x of 3'